# MathEvaluator parser

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How to? But i need a parser, that parse a string only once and has an interface like this

```
Func<double,double> MathEvaluator(string input)
```

or like this

```
LambdaExpression MathEvaluator(string input)
```

does it exists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need a fast runtime expression parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392022/i-need-a-fast-runtime-expression-parser)

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312225/best-free-c-sharp-math-parser-using-variables-user-defined-functions-custom-op) thread, quoting the results, that were provided by the answers of [Rick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/770263/rick), [Oliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/177710/oliver) and [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166132/max).

- [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/)
- [Math Parser .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274093/Math-Parser-NET)
- [muParser](http://muparser.beltoforion.de/)
- [Expression Parser](http://www.lundin.info/mathparser.aspx)
- [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/)
- [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=.net%20math%20parser)

You need to ponder, which fits your requirements best. E.g. Math Parser .NET supports `^` for powers and the others don't.

Comment: Yet another math parser is [YAMP](https://github.com/FlorianRappl/YAMP) (pardon the pun). Extensive list of mathematical functions, written entirely in C# and even available as a portable class library for Windows Store, Windows Phone and Silverlight applications.

Comment: I don't need parse it every time it calls, i need get a Delegate with function. For example, input

2*x*cos(x)+3*x*x*sin(x)

it's not algebraic parser, it's math evaluator, that return a function, that i can call with any parameters. Now i solved it like i post below. Iron python = it's good, cuz of using eval(...), but i don't like multilanguage project.

Answer (score 1):

so i maked a lib, if u want, you can use it, it's fine enough i think. There's some regex, that replace structures like a^b to Math.Pow(a,b) etc. It might be better, but it's hard work for me, but i'm working on it.

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

namespace MathEvalNS
{
public class MathEvaluator
{
    private readonly Delegate parsedFunction;
    private readonly string normalized;
    public double Invoke(double x)
    {
        if (parsedFunction == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("No function to invoke");
        return (double)parsedFunction.DynamicInvoke(x);
    }
    private const string Begin =
        @"using System;
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class LambdaCreator 
    {
        public static Func<double,double> Create()
        {
            return (x)=>";
        private const string End = @";
        }
    }
}";

    public MathEvaluator(string input)
    {
        normalized = Normalize(input);
        var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters { GenerateInMemory = true };
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, Begin + normalized + End);
        try
        {
            var cls = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("MyNamespace.LambdaCreator");
            var method = cls.GetMethod("Create", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
            parsedFunction = (method.Invoke(null, null) as Delegate);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }

    private string Normalize(string input)
    {
        return input.ReplaceMath().ReplacePow().ReplaceMultipling().ReplaceToDoubles();
    }
}

public static class StringHelper
{
    public static string ReplaceMultipling(this string input)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input, @"(\d+)(x)", @"$1*$2");
    }

    public static string ReplacePow(this string input)
    {
        var result = input.ReplacePow(@"(\d*x)\^(\d+\.?\d*)");
        return result.ReplacePow(@"\(([^\^]+)\)\^(\d+\.?\d*)");
    }

    private static string ReplacePow(this string input, string toReplace)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input, toReplace, "Math.Pow($1,$2)");
    }

    public static string ReplaceToDoubles(this string input)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input, @"(\d+)(?:[^\.]\d+)", "$1.0");
    }

    public static string ReplaceMath(this string input)
    {
        return
            input.ReplaceMath("sin", @"Math.Sin")
                 .ReplaceMath("cos", @"Math.Cos")
                 .ReplaceMath("ctg", @"1.0/Math.Tan")
                 .ReplaceMath("tg", @"Math.Tan");
    }

    private static string ReplaceMath(this string input, string name, string dotNetName)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input, name, dotNetName, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a MathParser: http://github.com/MathewSachin/MathParser

I Expect that what you want can be done like this:

```
Fuc<double, double> Parse(string Expression)
{
    MathParser P = new MathParser();
    Variable V = new Variable("x", 0); // The Variable you use with default value
    P.Variables.Add(V);

    P.Parse(Expression);

    return (Input) =>
        {
            V.Value = Input;
            return P.Evaluate();
        }
}
```

The Only thing i'm afraid is of Garbage Collection.