# Datatype to store math expressions and do operations with

Tags: c#, math, types, expression

I would like to store math expressions and do operations with, something like:

```
a=x^2+2x+1
b=2x+3
c=a+b
writeln(c(4))  -  would calculate and write the answer of 36
```

Is there a math library that allows this kind of coding in C# ?

Comment: A little bit of parsing and you can execute these as a C# snippet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a math library per se, but you could certainly do what you are showing us here with [delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  Off the top of my head (EDIT: a little better example):

```
delegate int myDelegate(int x);

var a = new myDelegate(x => (Math.Pow(x, 2)) + (2*x) + 1));
var b = new myDelegate(x => (2*x) + 3);
var c = new myDelegate(x => a(x) + b(x));

Console.WriteLine(c(4));
//Output: 36
```

Comment: With delegates I can define functions and "store" them (not exactly, but sufficient for my purpose), however, I cannot make operations such as + - / * etc between delegates and "store" them in another new cell for future use. even if so, it's very crooked way to work with..

Comment: @user2558958: but you could call delegates on the result of other delegates.

Comment: Thanks Paul.. I could manage with this kind of solution.. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the same expressions every time, delegates are a good idea as @Paul Griffin suggested. But if you have very different expressions, you will likely have to build your own parsing algorithm or find an existing one. In this case it would be a duplicate of [Parse Math Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972854/parse-math-expression).