# Calculate a sum in 1 click c#

Tags: c#, calculator

Scenario:

- the form consists of 2 text boxes and a button.

  - in textBox1 the user inputs: `4+7-3+10`
  - the button is pressed
  - in textBox2 the output will work out the sum = `18`

Can this be achieved in c#? and if yes, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should look around first before asking this question. This is really easy to do and there are a number of ways you could do this.

Comment: you may look on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972854/parse-math-expression

Comment: If a calculator can do it, I'm sure C# can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be achieved with  [`System.Data.DataTable.Compute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var calculator = new DataTable();
int result = (int)calculator.Compute("4+7-3+10", null); // 18
```

Have a look at the remarks section of [`DataColumn.Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) to see what is supported.