# Split calculator expression with binary and unary operations

Tags: c#, split

I get string input like: `1+2*5+sin100-2` and In order to calculate it I need to make array that will look like:

```
1,+,2,*,5,+,sin,100,-,2
```

Is there easy solution to do this problem?
Currently I am doing it with loop on all the chars in the string but I want to know if c# offer easiest solution to this problem.

Comment: Show your *Currently i am doing it with loop* code

Comment: See the last two lines of my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35219507/3764814) ;-)

Comment: We cannot guess if there is any better solution then your current one as long as you do not provide the current one. However in any cases I guess this question should go to review-stack instead.

Comment: If you have already a working solution it's off-topic on SO anyway.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about reviewing or improving existing, working code and lacking a specific question statement are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may be able to get help on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You can get most of the way with simple regex on split:  `\b.\b`

Comment: @TimSchmelter is *questions about reviewing or improving existing, working code and lacking a specific question statement* in flagging options? Cause I can't find it!

Comment: @AlexJolig Close - off topic - fourth option : Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found easy solution.
 You could just write it instead of complain that there is no code in the question.

```
string expression;//my calculator expression
string[] operators;//array that contains both unary and binary operators.
for(int i=0;i<operators.length;i++)
{
   expression = expression.replace(operators[i]," "+operators[i]+ " ");
}
string[] Values= expression.split(" ");
```