# How to validate for numeric operand in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the folllowing code for only numbers in the texbox, but would also like to include only numeric operations too (+,-, *, etc). How would you code for this please.

```
private void txtCalculation_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{   
    e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Math Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972854/parse-math-expression)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want digits and +, -, *, / you should use something like this:

```
private char[] validChars = {'+', '-', '*', '/'};

private void txtCalculation_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {        
    e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !Array.Exists(validChars, e.KeyChar);
}
```

The array validChars defines additional chars which are valid. And with the [Array.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw84x8be(v=vs.110).aspx) method you are able to check if the array contains a value specified by the second parameter of the method - in this case `e.KeyChar`.