# How to add separator to numbers in a string expression

Tags: c#, string

I am going to create some thing like a calculator.

There is a TextBox to enter expression and result will be calculated based on entered values and operators. for example users can enter:

```
(12000+15000)/2
```

I want to add separator for entered numbers.So the observable expression in TextBox should be :

```
(12,000+15,000)/2
```

Comment: Have you take a look at .NET String.Format() class? More about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: the text box doesn't follow any  pattern

Comment: What platform you are using, WinForms, WPF, WebForms...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Math Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972854/parse-math-expression)

Answer (score 3):

Use System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace() in C#. [check it working here](http://rextester.com/KLZLV13962) 
msdn docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149475(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "(12000+15000)/2";
            string pattern = "\\d+";
            Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
            string result = rgx.Replace(input, callback);

            Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
            Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);   
        }

        static string callback(Match m)
        {
            return  string.Format("{0:#,#}", Convert.ToInt32(m.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```