# Value is either too large or too small for type 'int32' with multiplying only

Tags: vb.net

I viewed a lot of topic in this subject, and i knew this error is because the process involves a number larger than what int32 supports.

but in my project all the other 3 processes is completed successfully (add - subtract - divide), except multiplication.

for example, a big number like 9999999999 could be processed with the previously mentioned 3 processes, but with multiplying it gives the error mentioned in title.

I am using datatable.compute and this is my code:

```vb
Try
    Dim myvalue As String = CalculatorText.Text
    Dim calc As New DataTable()
    Dim result = CType(calc.Compute(myvalue, Nothing), Double)
    CalculatorResult.Text = result
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

**Edit:**
i am using datatable.compute to calculate multiple processes
e.g. (13 + 656 - 54 * 65 / 45) which is written in textbox (calcultorText).

when i try to multiply relatively small numbers, it gives this error:

[image]

while with large numbers, it is done without any problems:

[image]

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: I don't see any multiplication. Please add the code where the multiplication is performed to you question.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer for you. First, your usage is invalid. This is abuse of opportunity. It makes no sense once however. You've created a table without any columns. And then you call `Compute` where you pass some arbitrary math operation. Even that I don't know what is in `myvalue`, I can imagine, something like this `99999999 * 99999999`. And what for?

```vb
Dim calc As New DataTable()
Dim result = CType(calc.Compute(myvalue, Nothing), Double)
```

The `Compute` method was done for certain table operations as below.

```vb
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim t = New DataTable("x")
    t.Columns.Add("c1", GetType(Integer))

    t.Rows.Add(Integer.MaxValue)
    t.Rows.Add(Integer.MaxValue)
    ' ERROR! but replace column type with GetType(double) and works
    Dim res = t.Compute("Sum(c1) * 9999999999", Nothing)
    Console.WriteLine(res)
End Sub
```

As you see above, if you had a defined column with accommodating data type, you could calculate math expressions with large numerical outputs. But what you do, you don't calculate table expression, you are using `DataTable` ability in the wrong application.

You should probably write a parser and just load values into variables, that just do `x + y`. In fact, [this was already answered before here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972854/parse-math-expression)

A little hacky workaround can be this

```vb
t.Columns.Add("c1", GetType(double)) ' define a column
t.Rows.Add(1) ' Add "1" to a single row
' And multiply your expression by 1 as result of SUM, always
Dim res As Double = CType(t.Compute("Sum(c1) * 999999999999 * 9999999999", Nothing), Double)
```

That will work

Comment: This question is tagged VB.NET and not C#, so posting C# code in an answer is not really acceptable. If the OP had used both tags then fair enough but an answer should answer the question asked and this question s about VB.NET.

Comment: @jmcilhinney ok fixed

Comment: @T.S.
the 999999999999 was just for example not a fixed value, please look at the edited part above

Comment: @ManofTheWest The answer above explains