# VB.Net- Evaluating Mathematical Expression in a String

Tags: vb.net, string, math, expression, evaluate

Is there a method that allows me to evaluate a mathematical expression in a string? Example (Not actual Code):

Input = "2+2"

Output = SomeMethod(Input)

Output = 4

Update: Nevermind, I found a way around it by using DataTable.Compute.

Comment: Search SO for MSScriptControl.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doing math in vb.net like Eval in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452282/doing-math-in-vb-net-like-eval-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a math expression parser to handle this.

Here are some various open source options on CodePlex:

- [Simple Math Parser](http://simplemathparser.codeplex.com/)
- [Fast Lightweight Expression Evaluator](http://flee.codeplex.com/)
- [ILCalc](http://ilcalc.codeplex.com/)

A search will find many others...

Comment: Thanks for the input but are there any libraries in the .Net that can do this? I'd prefer not to use an external parser...I don't need anything complex as long as it can add, subtract, multiply, and divide.

Comment: @Leonardo: Not directly.  You can use CodeDom to generate this yourself, but it's a fair amount of work...

Comment: Hmmm I think I'll use CodeDom instead then, thanks for the help