# Label not displaying text in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Is there a reason why my code is not displaying the text in AnswerText.Text?

```
    Dim EquationValues() As String

    ' Split the array into a string array based on blank spaces
    EquationValues = DisplayTextBox.Text.Split(" "c)

    ' Declaring an integer as a counter for the loop
    Dim LoopCounter As Integer = 0

        ' Setting a for loop on the array and performing the operations
    For LoopCounter = 0 To EquationValues.Length - 1
        If EquationValues(LoopCounter) = "/" Then
            AnswerTextBox.Text = EquationValues(LoopCounter - 1) / EquationValues(LoopCounter + 1)
        End If

        If EquationValues(LoopCounter) = "*" Then
            AnswerTextBox.Text = EquationValues(LoopCounter - 1) * EquationValues(LoopCounter + 1)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Shouldn't you exit the look if one of the IF's condition is matched?

Comment: Yes. Are you saying I should include an else if? It doesn't show up even when there is only one if statement

Comment: I would imagine if there's no text than the if conditions aren't getting met. Can you stick a breakpoint where the values are set and make sure the code's getting hit?

Comment: yup its getting hit at each starting point of the ifs

Comment: I don't remember much of VB but try add something in the line 'of Exit For' inside the IF

Comment: But if I do an 'Exit For' then it'll exit where I place it right? Would that matter since it's not even showing the answer in the first place

Comment: What sort of equation r u typing?

Comment: I checked ur code in a VS it is working fine. http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g5a005fa18855e8339992254998f4094f2d76f149a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EquationValues is an array, checking the length is not what I think you are looking for. You are looking for the count...the number of indices in the array...try

```
For LoopCounter = 0 To EquationValues.Count - 1
```

I answered a previous question of your's regarding string parsing mathematical equations ([parsing string to equation with vb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916062/parsing-string-to-equation-with-vb)). That example handled * and /, perhaps that might have something of use for you.

Good Luck :)