# Performing mathematical calculations when operator is a custom character

Tags: vb.net

What would be the proper way to perform a mathematical calculation when the operator is a variable character.  In other words, the operation is not known at compile-time.  The operation needs to be dynamically chosen at run-time.

For instance, let's say I need to calculate the sum of `20 + 40`, but the `+` operator is stored in a `Char` variable, like this:

```
Dim operator As Char = "+"c    
Dim result As Long = 10 operator 20
```

Comment: what is a "custom char"?  You generally dont do math on characters at all

Comment: Why is this tagged `C#`? Where is `c` defined? `10 iPlus 20`? What is that even supposed to do?

Comment: @sab669 the `c` is the way to designate char since otherwise `"+"` would be a string

Comment: Are you asking how to define the "Operator" at run-time? IE, Maybe it is plus(+), maybe it is negate(-), maybe it is divide(/), etc???

Comment: `CType((10 + 20), Char)`?

Comment: I suspect this is almost a duplicate of this post, but not quite. Have a look ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178637/evaluate-mathematical-expression-from-a-string-using-vb   .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way would be to use a `Select Case` statement to perform the calculation using the correct operation based on the input character.  For instance:

```
' Binary, as in not unary nor ternary
Public Function PerformBinaryOperation(operand1 As Long, operator As Char, operand2 As Long)
    Select Case operator
        Case "+"c
            Return operand2 + operand2
        Case "-"c
            Return operand2 - operand2
        ' ...
    End Select
End Function
```

The more advanced solution is to write an expression parser to analyze an expression string, such as `"10 + 20"`, and turns it into an [expression tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree).  If you don't want to go through the trouble of writing your own parser, you could use one of the available libraries to do it, such as [NCalc](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/).

Another alternative to expression tree parsing is to generate a snippet of .NET code, and then dynamically build and execute that code at run-time.  For instance, if you did something like this:

```
Dim operator As Char = "+"c
Dim codeBuilder As New StringBuilder()
codeBuilder.AppendLine("Public Class MyOperation")
codeBuilder.AppendLine("    Public Function Calculate() As Long")
codeBuilder.AppendLine("         Return 10 " & operator & " 20")
codeBuilder.AppendLine("    End Function")
codeBuilder.AppendLine("End Class")
Dim myOperation As Object = ' ... compile code and instantiate object dynamically
Dim result As Long = myOperation.Calculate()
```

Traditionally, you would do that using the CodeDom classes to perform the dynamic compilation, but now with the new Roslyn compiler in .NET 4.6, you can use the new `Emit` functionality.  [Here](http://benohead.com/three-options-to-dynamically-execute-csharp-code/) is an article that introduces the various dynamic compilation options.

Comment: Typo: Your subtract operation has a plus sign.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Thanks, though you could have edited it yourself just as easily :)