# In-built function in VB.NET to evaluate a string

Tags: .net, string, vb.net, visual-studio

Is there a function in VB.NET which can evaluate an arithematic string?

e.g., When passed 4+5-2 it should return the result (7).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate mathematical expression from a string using VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178637/evaluate-mathematical-expression-from-a-string-using-vb)

Comment: That works for vb only!
I need it for vb.NET

Comment: @cmcodes What are you talking about??? "works for vb only"???

Comment: @Mary the Evaluate function mentioned by Alexandru Clonțea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DataTable:

```
Dim equation As String = "4+5-2"
Dim result = New DataTable().Compute(equation, Nothing)
```

Result is 7.

Comment: Thanks Man! It worked! Had to include `Imports System.Data` too! :)

Comment: Happy to help :)